# Remove item from array in a mongodb document using Doctrine ODM

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, doctrine-odm

I have a mongoDB document comprising the following structure:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("537b9731fa4634134c8b45aa"),
        "kpis" : [
                {
                        "id" : 4,
                        "value" : 3.78,
                        "entered" : Timestamp(1401377656, 9)
                }
        ]
}
```

I want to remove ALL kpi documents where the id is x. This is quite simple to do on the database directly using the pull command:

```
db.lead.update({}, {$pull:{"kpis":{id:5}}}, {multi:true});
```

However my (several) attempts to match this syntax using the doctrine ODM have failed:

```
    $qb->update()
       ->field('kpis')
       ->pull($qb->expr()->field('kpis.id')->equals($kpi->getId()))
       ->multiple(true)
       ->getQuery()
       ->execute();

    // I've also tried..

    $qb->update()
       ->field('kpis')
       ->pull($qb->expr()->field('kpis')->elemMatch(
            $qb->expr()->field('kpis.id')->equals($kpi->getId())
        ))
       ->multiple(true)
       ->getQuery()
       ->execute();
```

Nothing is removed. Am I using the query builder correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you want to do the following:

```
$qb->update()
    ->field('kpis')->pull(array('id' => $kpi->getId()))
    ->multiple(true)
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

You can use the `Query::debug()` method to dump the actual query generated by this. You should expect the following in the dumped `newObj` field:

```
{ "$pull": { "kpis": { "id": <number> }}}
```

---

To explain why your previous examples didn't work:

```
->field('kpis')
->pull($qb->expr()->field('kpis.id')->equals($kpi->getId()))
```

Here, you're creating the following query:

```
{ "$pull": { "kpis": { "kpis.id": <number> }}}
```

This would only match:

1. If each embedded object in the top-level `kpis` array had an embedded `kpis` object within it, which in turn had an `id` field that matched the number.
2. If the embedded objects in the top-level `kpis` array had their own `kpis` arrays consisting of embedded objects with an `id` field that matched. This would be MongoDB's [array element matching](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#match-an-array-element) coming into play.

In your second example, you have:

```
->field('kpis')
->pull($qb->expr()->field('kpis')->elemMatch(
    $qb->expr()->field('kpis.id')->equals($kpi->getId())
))
```

This would generate the following query:

```
{ "$pull": { "kpis": { "$elemMatch": { "kpis.id": <number> }}}}
```

I've never seen such syntax before, but I think the `$elemMatch` is superflous, since [`$pull`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) already takes criteria to match an array element as its argument. [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) is useful in a query when you're directly matching on an array field and don't mean to do a full equality match against the array elements (i.e. you *want* to provide criteria instead of an exact match).

Comment: Thanks, work for me. `->field('categories')->pull(['_id'=>new ObjectId($categoriesID)])`